# Screen support for xlarge screens?

Tags: android

In my application I want to only support normal and large screens, so I need to disable support for small and xlarge screens. The project build is set to 2.1, API Level 7, so I know xlarge screens aren't recognized by the manifest for that level. Does that mean that the application will automatically not support xlarge screens or am I going to have to change the project build to 2.3 to disable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare

```
<supports-screens android:resizeable=["true"| "false"]
              android:smallScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:normalScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:largeScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:xlargeScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:anyDensity=["true" | "false"]
              android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="integer"
              android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="integer"
              android:largestWidthLimitDp="integer"/>
```

in your manifest for what screens you want to support.

Comment: It wont accept xlargeScreens, since I'm building for 2.1.. So I'm getting the following error: "error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'xlargeScreens' in package 'android'"

Comment: Well it wouldnt hurt to build for 2.3 and just declare that you dont want to build for xlarge screens in your manifiest as i showed above.

Comment: The problem is, its for a client and they want the app built for 2.1, but they do not want xlarge screens to be supported, is there any other way to disable it?

Comment: Answer is incomplete without the solution of the above question. Provide some information about the above question to complete this answer.